# Prism Command Binding using Parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, command, parameter-passing, prism

I have a working hyperlink as follow:

XAML:

```
 <TextBlock >
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >
       <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Constructor:

```
 navHomeViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavHomeView);
```

Command:

```
     private readonly ICommand navHomeViewCommand;
    public ICommand NavHomeViewCommand
    {
        get
        { return navHomeViewCommand; }
    }
    private void NavHomeView()
    {
        int val;
        val = PersonSelected.PersonKnownID);
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
        parameters.Add("To", val);
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", new Uri("HomeView", UriKind.Relative), parameters);
    }
```

If I want to have multiple hyperlinks such as...

```
     <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >
       <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName}" />
    </Hyperlink>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >
       <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName2}" />
    </Hyperlink>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >
       <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName3}" />
    </Hyperlink>
```

Do I have to make a new Command for each or is there a way to pass a different parameter (int) for each hyperlink to the existing NavHomeView command so I can reuse this command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a complete solution that worked for me:

1. Use CommandParameter (as per Dmitry - Spasiba!)

   ```
   <TextBlock>
       <Hyperlink CommandParameter="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnown2ID}"
                  Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >
           <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName2}" />
       </Hyperlink>
   </TextBlock>
   ```
2. Change DelegateCommand to use object parameter

   ```
   navHomeViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(NavHomeView);
   ```
3. Command Properties remain unchanged but method changed to use parameter:

   ```
   private readonly ICommand navHomeViewCommand;
   public ICommand NavHomeViewCommand
   {
       get { return navHomeViewCommand; }
   }

   private void NavHomeView(object ID)
   {
       int val = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
       var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
       parameters.Add("To", val);
      _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", new Uri("HomeView", UriKind.Relative), parameters);
   }
   ```

Comment: word of warning, don't use a null check in your can execute  call, as command always initialises with null parameter, command parameter is then set but doesn't then refresh the command's CanExecute binding,

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'CommandParameter' property of the Hyperlink.

```
 <Hyperlink Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" CommandParameter="1" >
       <Run Text="{Binding PersonSelected.PersonKnownName}" />
 </Hyperlink>
```